# Can someone help me for the error no match for operator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string  str="", str1 = "", str2 = "" ;
    string math="10";

    cout << "Enter a string:\n";

    //Get input string.  Use newline as terminator and store the string in str1
    getline(cin,str1,'\n');

    //limit str1 to 100 characters
    str1 = str1.substr(0,100);

    //Identify if somethings wrong on the input
    if(str1=="")
    {
    cout << "You entered nothing you silly nod!: " << endl;
    return 0;
    }



    for(int i=0;i <str1.length();i++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        string temp = "";
        if(isalpha(str1[i]) || str[i] == ' ')
        {


        //break up  the string with spaces in the same places.  This trim the '-' off the end 
        before adding the space.
            if(str1[i] == ' ')
            {
                str2 = str2.substr(0, str2.length() -1) + str[i];
            }
            else
            {
                //convert the char to int and substract the offset
                //stringstream is an easy way to convert numbers to strings.
                ss << (int)(tolower(str1[i])-86);
                ss >> temp;                
                str2 += temp + "-";
            }
        }
    }
    //Trim the '-' off the final string
    math * str2;
    str2= str2.substr(0, str2.length() -1);

    cout << "Your generated number: " << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl <<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `math * str2;` to do?  `std::string`s are not multipliable.

Comment: *stringstream is an easy way to convert numbers to strings.* -- `istringstream` is also an easy way to parse data with spaces, yet you didn't use it for that purpose when you could have done so.

Comment: so I converted a letter to a number then I would like to multiply them

Comment: You don't have any numbers.  You have strings of characters that look like numbers, but those are not numbers.  To get numbers you need to convert the strings into numbers and then store those values in a variable that has a integer or floating point data type (`int`, `double`, ect.)

Comment: Even if you had numbers, what would `math * str2;` accomplish?  Where is the result of the multiplication stored?

Comment: thank you guys for your tips/help I changed that part to a random gen number (can't get through it i'm still a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

For String there is no operator " * " defined. Since you want to multiply numbers use e.g. int. Here you can find a way how it could be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1 = "", str2 = "";
    int math = 10;

    cout << "Enter a string:\n";

    //Get input string.  Use newline as terminator and store the string in str1
    getline(cin, str1, '\n');

    //limit str1 to 100 characters
    str1 = str1.substr(0, 100);

    //Identify if somethings wrong on the input
    if (str1 == "")
    {
        cout << "You entered nothing you silly nod!: " << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    vector<int> intergers;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(str1[i]) || str1[i] == ' ')
        {
            //break up  the string with spaces in the same places.  This trim the '-' off the end before adding the space.
            if (str1[i] == ' ')
            {
                str2 = str2.substr(0, str2.length() - 1) + str1[i];
            }
            else
            {
                //convert the char to int and substract the offset
                intergers.push_back(tolower(str1[i]) - 86);
                str2 += to_string(tolower(str1[i]) - 86) + "-";
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto val : intergers)
    {
        cout << math << " * " << val << " = " << math * val << endl;
    }

    //Trim the '-' off the final string
    str2 = str2.substr(0, str2.length() - 1);

    cout << "Your generated number: " << endl;
    cout << str2 << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```